# How to write code examples in LyX?

Tags: lyx, verbatim, code-snippets

I'm using LyX for Hebrew documents. When I add a Verbatim environment with English language, sometimes after a little editing the language change automatically to LaTeX and the compiled Verbatim text shows up RTL and swapped ('hello' becomes 'olleh').
How can I change language back to English? Or is there a better way to show programming code inside a document?

Comment: Have you considered using the listings package? In LyX, go to the Insert menu and choose "Program Listing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LyX, go to the Insert menu and choose "Program Listing".

Comment: @omrikap if you find this solution helpful, click the 'up' arrow above the answer's score and the checkmark ✓.

Comment: At the moment I don't have enough reputation, but I'll 'up' it when I'll have.. :)